# How can I parse a website using Selenium and Beautifulsoup in python?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

New to programming and figured out how to navigate to where I need to go using Selenium. I'd like to parse the data now but not sure where to start. Can someone hold my hand a sec and point me in the right direction?

Any help appreciated -

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Assuming you are on the page you want to parse, Selenium stores the source HTML in the driver's `page_source` attribute. You would then load the `page_source` into `BeautifulSoup` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://news.ycombinator.com')

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.find_all('title'):
    print(tag.text)
    
Hacker News
```

Comment: @root Haha, a nice holiday exchange.

Comment: @RocketDonkey -     soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
NameError: name 'html' is not defined
This is the error I get, any suggestions

Comment: @twitchaftercoffee So in the code above, `html` refers to the source of the page. Whenever you reach your page, your `driver` object will have an attribute called `page_source`, and the code above assigns that value to `html`. Note that this step isn't really necessary as you could just pass `driver.page_source` directly to BeautifulSoup (as root did above).

Comment: @RocketDonkey - Worked, doesn't toss up errors, but doesn't actually print anything

Comment: @twitchaftercoffee So the example up there looks for a `title` tag, so in the odd case the page doesn't have one then nothing will show. Try running `print soup.prettyify()` - do you see anything?

Comment: Make that `soup.prettify()`...

Comment: @RocketDonkey I want to do the opposite thing. I want to select a element using beautifulsoup and then perform action using chrome driver.How can I do this

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH`.

Answer (score 23):

As your question isn't particularly concrete, here's a simple example. To do something more useful read the BS [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You will also find plenty of examples of selenium (and BS )usage here in SO.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://webpage.com')

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

#do something useful
#prints all the links with corresponding text

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link.get('href',None),link.get_text()
```

Comment: +1, didn't see this come up as I was typing :)

Comment: For this, I got     soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

Comment: the code is ok. `browser=webdriver.Firefox()` defines `browser`. just copy the code directly...you must have made a mistake.

Comment: @root - got it, but did not print anything. Running it outside of python by python xx.py

Comment: `soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)` it's the same with chrome

Comment: @root I want to do the opposite thing. I want to select a element using beautifulsoup and then perform action using chrome driver.How can I do this

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to use Selenium? For this reasons I used [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), it's very powerful, and you can do what ever you want.

I can give you a sample code, that I just wrote, just change url and you good to go:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys, signal

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadProgress.connect(self._progress)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.frame = self.page().currentFrame()

    def _progress(self, progress):
        print str(progress) + "%"

    def _loadFinished(self):
        print "Load Finished"
        html = unicode(self.frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        print soup.prettify()
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    br = Browser()
    url = QUrl('http://web site that can contain javascript.com')
    br.load(url)
    br.show()
    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I have found PyQt4 a humongous pain to use.  Depending on OP's requirements, just using BeautifulSoup is probably a lot easier.

Comment: what you mean, " just using BeautifulSoup is probably a lot easier."

Comment: OP here, Beautiful soup allowed me to nav to the section I want to parse very easy. I'd prefer to stick with it if possible.

Comment: I'd love to use pyqt4 instead of selenium - it's so much faster. but when I install it via windows binary - and try and import it and run that code, it can't find the library. Please help

Comment: @Vor I am looking solution to port my CLI Selenium tool to GUI based, Will an embed browser control in PyQT can be accessed by Selenium?