# How to parse text in websites that display additional text after clicking a button, but that text is not in the base html

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the blog links on this page:http://hypem.com/track/26ed4/Skizzy+Mars+-+Way+I+Live

You click more to reveal the links. However only one link is visible in the html source. I am using BeautifulSoup, how would I get the other links?

Comment: Either BS + Mechanize OR Scrapy.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried BeautifulSoup. However the html source doesn't display all the links, and BeautifulSoup can only parse the html. So I am at a loss as to what to do. If you tell me other techniques to try I will try them and report back

Comment: This answer looks promising, I will investigate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want the links to the the blogs that appear when I click "more". using the method in the answer I mentioned, I can get the rendered html, but I don't know how to trigger the "more" button programatically. Once I can do that I'm fine as I can just use regex/beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stay with `requests`+`BeautifulSoup` approach. You just need to simulate the underlying requests going to the server when you click the `More blogs` button and scroll down the page.

Here's the code that prints all of the blog post image titles from the http://hypem.com/blogs page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def extract_blogs(content):
    first_page = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for link in first_page.select('div.directory-blog img'):
        print link.get('title')

# extract blogs from the main page
response = requests.get('http://hypem.com/blogs')
extract_blogs(response.content)

# paginate over rest results until there would be an empty response
page = 2
url = 'http://hypem.com/inc/serve_sites.php?featured=true&page={page}'

while True:
    response = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    if not response.content.strip():
        break
    extract_blogs(response.content)
    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Heart and Soul
Avant-Avant
Different Kitchen
Ladywood 
Orange Peel
Phonographe Corp
...
Stadiums & Shrines
Caipirinha Lounge
Gorilla Vs. Bear
ISO50 Blog
Fluxblog
Music ( for robots)
```

Hope this gives you at least the basic idea on how to scrape the web page contents in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I understand everything but how you chose that particular url. What is the logic behind that page/how do you know to use that one?

Comment: @Andrew I've used browser developer tools (in my case Chrome) - Network tab - there you can inspect browser-server requests taking place.