# Web Crawling in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-crawler

New to web crawling :)
I want the list of mobile phones from flipkart. The url I am using is https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=categorytree

The only div i want to pull off is the names of each phone. class of that div is "**_3wU53n**"

Here is my code which returns an empty list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=categorytree"
source = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "html.parser")
data = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'_3wU53n'})
print data
```

kindly help.

Comment: There is no class '_3wU53n' in content.
Check for yourself in the source code - view-source:https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=categorytree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python
Refer to this answer for help in retrieving dynamically generated DOM.

Comment: this is for the first item in the list: <div class="_3wU53n">Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro (Gold, 16 GB)</div>. Instead of viewing source code, please inspect it.

Comment: Please check the question in the 2nd comment I mentioned.