# Why render / requests-html doesn't scrape dynamic content?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

Long story short : switched from Selenium to Requests(-html).

Works OK but not in every case.

Page : https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/1/1

Upon load it charges dynamic content with english games (example : Sheffield United - West Ham).

But when I try to do this :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/1/1/1')
r.html.render()
print(r.html.text) # I also tried print(r.html.html)
```

the games don't show in the output.

Why ? Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the values of dynamic html content using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python)

Comment: Simply because the "output" is not included in the page. In the Browser it is added to the DOM of the page by Javascript. Request does not run the Javascript. Selenium uses a browser to work.

Comment: but requests-html wasn't it supposed to handle JavaScript Support ??? https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/#javascript-support

Comment: i tried to find the ajax json with the data, with no luck yet (unsure how to perform this)

Comment: As OP says, it is the [Requests-HTML](https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/) library he is using, which should be able to render JS and then inspect dynamically generated elements in the DOM, unlike Requests.
Like OP, I've also experienced this to be quite sketchy though: On some sites, `render()` works and on others it doesn't. Would be great to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add timeout, it should work, sorry this must be a comment but I cannot comment..

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/1/1')
r.html.render(timeout=20)
print(r.html.html)
session.close()
```

Comment: when im running, i get this `RuntimeWarning`: `C:\Applications__\python372\lib\site-packages\pyee\_base.py:81: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Browser._targetCreated' was never awaited
  f(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback.`

and then nothing is happening, it never stops from running. even with CTRL+C i cant stop the process.

Comment: How can I use this with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the `sleep` parameter in the render function to wait for a few seconds before rendering was the only thing that worked for me:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/1/1')
r.html.render(sleep=10)
print(r.html.html)
session.close()
```

From the [requests-html documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/):

```
render(retries: int = 8, script: str = None, wait: float = 0.2, scrolldown=False, **sleep: int = 0**, reload: bool = True, timeout: Union[float, int] = 8.0, keep_page: bool = False, cookies: list = [{}], send_cookies_session: bool = False)[source]
```

> Reloads the response in Chromium, and replaces HTML content with an updated version, with JavaScript executed.

Parameters:

- `retries` – The number of times to retry loading the page in Chromium.
- `script` – JavaScript to execute upon page load (optional).
- `wait` – The number of seconds to wait before loading the page, preventing
  timeouts (optional).
- `scrolldown` – Integer, if provided, of how many
  times to page down.
- **`sleep` – Integer, if provided, of how many seconds to sleep after initial render.**
- `reload` – If False, content will not be loaded from
  the browser, but will be provided from memory.
- `keep_page` – If True will allow you to interact with the browser page through `r.html.page`.
- `send_cookies_session` – If True send HTMLSession.cookies convert.
- `cookies` – If not empty send cookies.