# why does my web scraping code returns []?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping some data from this web site, https://eleccionesnacionales.corteelectoral.gub.uy/ResumenResultados.htm, I inspected the page and found this

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da9UX.png)

knowing that, i coded this, but its just returns "[]" i ve been with this for like 2 hours but I cant find a solution

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://eleccionesnacionales.corteelectoral.gub.uy/ResumenResultados.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")

votos = soup.find_all("span", class_="subtotal sin-margin sin-padding ")
print(votos)
```

Comment: Did you inspect the DOM of the page or the actual source code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this JSON API.
I don't know why this number "1591673487333" but most properly it's his date.

```
https://eleccionesnacionales.corteelectoral.gub.uy/JSON/ResumenGeneral_D.json?1591673487333
```

this output of this JSON file https://pastebin.com/yXvkArBv

Use this code to generate number. like this "1591673487333"

```
import time
millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(millis)
```

Example:

```
import time
import urllib.request, json 

millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://eleccionesnacionales.corteelectoral.gub.uy/JSON/ResumenGeneral_D.json?" + str(millis)) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
    print(data[0]['EleccionNacional'][0]['LemaNombre']) # Partido Frente Amplio
    print(data[0]['EleccionNacional'][0]['Total']) # 949376
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you an output

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://eleccionesnacionales.corteelectoral.gub.uy/ResumenResultados.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")
# print(soup)
votos = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"subtotal sin-margin sin-padding"})
for span in votos:
    print(span.text)
print(votos)
```

This is a general procedure for any websites. But the website that you have given is using some template engine and the data is presented as some variable, here as

```
{{Total | format . 0 }}
```

The output of the program will be

```
{{Total | format . 0 }}
{{Total | format . 0 }}
[<span class="subtotal sin-margin sin-padding">{{Total | format . 0 }}</span>, <span class="subtotal sin-margin sin-padding">{{Total | format . 0 }}</span>]
```

However if you would like to get it, refer this page: [How to retrieve the values of dynamic html content using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python)

It will use selenium and chrome drivers to get the actual rendered site and use it to **scrape** data.