# List links in web page with python

Tags: python, request

I am trying to write a python script that lists all the links in a webpage that contain some substring. The problem that I am running into is that the webpage has multiple "pages" so that it doesn't clutter all the screen. Take a look at https://www.go-hero.net/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++ for an example.

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.go-hero.net/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
links = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in links:
  link = tag.get('href', None)
  if link is not None and 'GetSource' in link:
    print(link)
```

Any suggestions on how I might get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit/Update:** Using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), you could click the page links before scraping the html to collect all the content into the html. Many/most websites with pagination don't collect all the text in the html when you click through the pages, but I noticed that the example you provided does. Take a look [at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960326/how-can-i-parse-a-website-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-in-python) for a quick example of making Selenium work with BeautifulSoup. Here is how you could use it in your code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
original_url = "https://www.go-hero.net/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++"
driver.get(original_url)

# click the links for pages 1-29
for i in range(1, 30):
    path_string = '/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++#page-' + str(i)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href=' + path_string + ']').click()

# scrape from the accumulated html
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')

# proceed as normal from here
for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href', None)
    if link is not None and 'GetSource' in link:
        print(link)
```

Original Answer: For the [link](https://www.go-hero.net/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++) you provided above, you could simply loop through possible urls and run your scraping code in the loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
original_url = "https://www.go-hero.net/jam/17/solutions/1/1/C++"

# scrape from the original page (has no page number)
response = requests.get(original_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
links = soup.find_all('a')

# prepare to scrape from the pages numbered 1-29
# (note that the original page is not numbered, and the next page is "#page-1")
url_suffix = '#page-'

for i in range(1, 30):
    # add page number to the url
    paginated_url = original_url + url_suffix + str(i)
    response = requests.get(paginated_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
    # append resulting list to 'links' list
    links += soup.find_all('a')

# proceed as normal from here
for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href', None)
    if link is not None and 'GetSource' in link:
        print(link)
```

I don't know if you mind that you'll get duplicates in your results. You will get duplicate results in your `link` list as the code currently stands, but you could add the links to a Set or something instead to easily remedy that.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't actually get the links for page 2, 3, 4, etc. Instead we get the same links from page 0 over and over again. This can be validated by looking up some username from another page.

Comment: I added a better approach, and left the original approach at the bottom of the answer. The approach I added uses selenium to do what you want. I believe the original approach does work in loading page 2, 3, 4, etc., but you are right that it also loads page 0 a total of thirty times.