# Unable to identify elements on the webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

There are few check boxes on the screen.These check boxes appear dynamically i.e.. sometimes there can be 2 check boxes and sometimes more. I am suppose to click at one check box and then click on the download button, in the next step un-check the checked and click on the next check box and then again click on the download button. This process goes on until i click once on all the check boxes. the issue is that i am unable to identify the check box on the webpage. [image]

and i have to individually click on each checkbox and then on download button, then move to the next checkbox and do the

Comment: Have you tried looking at the page HTML source?

Comment: yea i did... the id's keep on changing for the checkboxes

Comment: You don't have to use the id to find items.  You can search based on their type, name, or even their location within the page.

Comment: Apparently,  i can only see                                                                     
  <input type="checkbox" class="yui-dt-checkbox" id="yui-gen76">  and i have to individually click on each checkbox and then on download button, then move to the next checkbox and do the same

Comment: Update the question with this info along with some more of ouerHTML for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Beautifulsoup to identify all the input checkboxes and loop over them to check each through selenium.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

checkboxes = BS.findAll('input', {'type':'checkbox'})
for cb in checkboxes:
    #do the checking
```

[How can I parse a website using Selenium and Beautifulsoup in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960326/how-can-i-parse-a-website-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Comment: Yea that's not working, It is unable to locate the checkbox